# In ASP.NET Core 3.1, how to reuse Service object across requests?

Tags: c#, .net-core, singleton

I use `JHipster` to generate a project with `Angular` and `.NET Core 3.1` (Java is my current stack, I don't work with .Net since 2012). Project's structure is quite simple, Controller --> Business service --> DAO. The project has few hundred line of code.
At a Business service object, I store data in some Dictionary and start a watch dog thread inside constructor. But `.NET Core` recreate Business object to handle each request, so that all my data is gone away and I spam a lot of threads. I tried to add singleton at Startup.cs but didn't work

```
services.AddSingleton<T,K>();
```

Is there anyway to reuse Business service object in `.Net Core`? (Or I have to switch to Java)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `T` and `K` represent in `services.AddSingleton<T,K>();` and why it didn't work for you, but the method for reusing services across request is in fact registering them as singleton.

If you have a controller that takes dependency on a `IFooBusinessObject` service like -

```
public class CoolController : ControllerBase
{
    public CoolController(IFooBusinessObject businessObject)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

and you have a concrete class `FooBusinessObject` that implements `IFooBusinessObject`, then register the service in `Startup` class as -

```
services.AddSingleton<IFooBusinessObject, FooBusinessObject>();
```

If your controller depends on a concrete class `MyCoolBusinessObject` instead, like -

```
public class CoolController : ControllerBase
{
    public CoolController(MyCoolBusinessObject businessObject)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

then register it like -

```
services.AddSingleton<MyCoolBusinessObject>();
```

Comment: I did exactly the same, but it just didn't work :)